# mongodb find element in array or less but no other

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection:

```
{
  "title": "First Item",
  "attributes": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "Alpha"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "Bravo"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "Charlie"
      }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Second Item",
  "attributes": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "Alpha"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "Bravo"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "Tango"
      }
  ]
}
```

Trying search with these values for "attributes.text" field:

```
{ "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta" }
```

I want to find only "First Item" document that contains at least these keys but no others.

**But** trying these values:

```
{ "Alpha", "Bravo", "Delta" }
```

or

```
{ "Alpha", "Bravo" }
```

I do **not** want to find any result (beacuse "Charlie" is missing).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to match values in the `attributes` object array. The following query will select all documents in the collection where the `text` field value of the `attribute` object array is either "Alpha", "Bravo" or "Delta":

```
dbo.collection.find({
    "attributes.text": { 
         "$in": ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Delta"]
     }
});
```

This will return the two documents:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551187bae3757367bf8bd915"),
    "title" : "First Item",
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "text" : "Alpha"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "text" : "Bravo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "text" : "Charlie"
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551187bae3757367bf8bd916"),
    "title" : "Second Item",
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "text" : "Alpha"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "text" : "Bravo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "text" : "Tango"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This isn't behaviour I want.
I desire behaviours that I describe in my question.
TY